# Format Description of WorkItem other than Bug

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, formatting, workitem

I´m looking for a way to format the **Description** of WorkItems that are of type `UserStory`, `Issue` or `Task`, but the ToolBar for changing Font, FontSize, FontColor, that is available to format the **Steps to Reproduce** of `Bugs` isn´t available for those WorkItems.

I would like to know if its possible to enable the ToolBar for the Description.

I have tested this with the TFS-Plugin in Visual Studio 2010 and 2012. We are using TFS 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in TFS 2010 because the default description field is Plaintext not HTML. In TFS 2012 this field has been [changed](http://bartwullems.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/tfs-2012-work-item-description-field-is.html) to HTML.

You "could" create a new Description field "MyCompany.DescriptionHtml" for example of the type HTML, but you would have to ensure that no-one (or any reports, etc) ever used System.Description for anything. 
Also, you would need to migrate all existing descriptions to the new Field.